# lob_data_space_id in sys.tables MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, system

I want to know the meaning of the lob_data_space_id column in sys.tables table.
What parameter does it describe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if columns of table include `varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)`, `xml` datatype the `lob_data_space_id` will be `1`

[sys.tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> A nonzero value is the ID of the data space (filegroup or partition scheme) that holds the large object binary (LOB) data for this table. Examples of LOB data types include varbinary(max), varchar(max), geography, or xml.

For example:

There are three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE T(I INT,J VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE T1(I INT,J VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE T2(I INT,J XML)

SELECT lob_data_space_id,* 
FROM  sys.tables
```

- `T` There aren't any columns  contain `varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)`, `xml`. so `lob_data_space_id` will be `0`
- `T1` and `T2` columns contain `varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)`, `xml`. so `lob_data_space_id` will be `1`

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0f2c3aafddc7574ee3b86fc0982e894)